# Java: setText GUI code in a text based rpg game

Tags: java, swing

I am currently making this text-based rpg game with a simple GUI. I was happy to find the good start at it but then there is something I stumbled upon that made me stop coding for a while.

If you are making this in console, you could easily use this code to pause the movements of the characters for a while, like:

```
System.out.println("[enemy]");
Thread.sleep(1000);
System.out.println("The local guard waves his sword and tries to stab you in the back, but you quickly parried and tried for a counterattack but you failed.");
```

If you are doing this on a `JTextArea`, you'd use the `setText` but 
if you use `Thread.sleep` it doesnt work and coding `setText` again, would erase the old text and replace it with the new text, so the records of the fight will not be fully displayed on the game. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Can you please pick an answer!

Comment: how can I do that? It doesn't have any vote this answer?

Comment: The answer you like, you just click on the green tick next to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the setText part, you should have a variable which will hold the text and when you want to add a string, you append it and set the text again:

```
String text ="[enemy]";
textfield.setText(text);
text+= "\nblablabla ..";
textfield.setText(text);
```

**UPDATE:**

Some are suggesting to use the append method which is relatively good. Sometimes in the game you would like to append and sometimes replace the whole text (a new character talks), I would recommend something like this:

```
textfield.setText("[enemy]\n");
textfield.append("blablabla");

//When someone else wanna talk:

thread.Sleep(1000);
textfield.setText("[me]\n");
textfield.append("moreblablabla");
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `append` to append instead of replace. That is the easy part.

The hard part: You have to change your program flow. In Swing there exists a single thread for dispatching GUI events, the event dispatching thread. You should not set the EDT to `sleep` or do any other long-running operations in it. This will freeze the GUI, it can't respond to anything and will not repaint.

Instead you should either start a new thread for the logic flow and dispatch operations that have to be executed on the EDT (everything that manipulates the GUI) with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` or, in this case maybe better, `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait`.

Or you should embrace an event driven control flow, e.g. you could use a `Timer` to output the second text later.

A program flow that works well with single-threaded console programs is not the right approach for multi-threaded GUI applications (and every GUI application is automatically multi-threaded).

Answer (score 1):

You could also use **append()** function. See [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29).

```
jTextField.append("Foo\n");
jTextField.append("Bar\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `append()` instead of `setText()`. Method `append()` will append new text at the end of the old text.